# Good features to track? AR Drone 2

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tracking, shapes, detection

I am trying to implement object tracking from the camera(just one camera, no Z info). Camera has 720*1280 resolution, but I usually rescale it to 360*640 for faster processing.

This tracking is done from the robots camera and I want a system which would be as robust as possible.

I will list what I did so far and what were the results.

1. I tried to do ***colour tracking***, I would convert image to hsv colour space, do thresholding, some morphological transformations and then find the object with the biggest area. This approach made a fair tracking of the object, unless there are no other object with the same colour. As I was looking for the max and if there are any other objects bigger than the one I need, robot would go towards the bigger one
2. Then, I decided to track ***circled objects of the specific colour***. However, it was difficult to find under different angles
3. Then, I decided to track ***square objects of specific colour***. I used this

> ```
>        // Approximate contour with accuracy proportional
>         // to the contour perimeter
>         cv::approxPolyDP(
>                 cv::Mat(contours[i]),
>                 approx,
>                 cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true) * 0.02,
>                 true
>         );
> ```

and then I checked this condition

> if (approx.size() >= 4 && approx.size() <= 6)

and afterwards I checked for

> solidity > 0.85 and aspect ratio between 0.85 and 1.15

But still result is not as robust as I would expect, especially the size. If there are several squares it would not find the needed one.

---

So, now I need some suggestions on what other ***features*** of the object could I use to improve tracking and how? As I mentioned above several times, one of the main problems is ***size***. And I know the size of the object. However, I am not sure how I can make use of it, because I do not know the distance of the object from the camera and that is why I am not sure how to represent its size in pixel representation so that I can eliminate any other blobs that do not fall into that range.

***UPDATE***

In the third step, I described how I am going to detect squares with specific colour. Below are the examples of what I am getting.

I used this HSV range for the red colour:

> Scalar(250, 129, 0), Scalar(255, 255, 255), params to OpenCV's inRange function
>
> HMIN = 250, HMAX = 255; SMIN = 129, SMAX = 255; VMIN = 0, VMAX = 255;
>   (Would like to see your suggestions on tweaking this values as well)

So, in this picture you can see the processing; gaussian blurring (5*5),
morphological closing two times (5*5). And the image with the label "result" shows the tracked object (please look at the green square).

[image: Thresholding and tracking based on HSV colour space 1]

On the second frame, you can see that it cannot detect the "red square". The only main difference between these two pics is that I bended down the lid of the laptop (please look closer if you cannot notice). I suppose this happens because of the ***illumination***, and this causes the thresholding to give not desired results.

[image: Bended the lid of the laptop]

The only way, I can think of is doing two separate processing on the image. First, to do thresholding based on the colour as I was doing above. Then if I find the object to move to the next frame. If not to use [this opencv's find squares](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp) method.

However, this method will involve doing too much of processing of the image.

Comment: Have you tried to use RGB color space and check if the red layer value is bigger than others for each pixel. Also, blurring the image you can reduce the noise in some areas.

Comment: @goe no I haven't tried doing it on RGB,  but yes I will try that too, but not sure about that. And I do blur the image for the noise reduction

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using some marker [ARUCO](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html#gsc.tab=0) or the like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one template which is an image of target object image, you try to use feature matching with SIFT or SURF. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXn69V-1kEM

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html

Note 1: you can use feature matching in gray scale which can improve your processing time

Note 2: You can try alternative regression methods like artificial neural networks instead of RANSAC

Comment: So, you suggest detecting object with a solid colour and specific shape with SIFT or SURF?

Comment: Using specific pattern is better than solid color. But you can try solid color

Comment: This kind of feature detectors detects characteristic points in the image, and applies a description to those points. A solid color surface has not (in theory) characteristic points (is a constant color surface), so I don't thing it is a correct solution.

Comment: @goe I completely agree with you

Comment: So what do you want? Flying robot with solid color¿

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your requirement that you only need to track a flat region which is of a red color. So, you already have two characteristics for tracking purpose :

- Flat Region
- Red Color

Here's an algorithm for doing that :

- Detect flat regions in an image computing variance for a region. A region with low variance will likely be a flat region.
- Classify it as an object of interest if it's hue value is close to red.
- Then do some voting from neighboring pixels to get the exact binary map for the object.

Other thing you can try is tweak Harris Corner Detector for your purpose : 
[Harris Corner Detector](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html#gsc.tab=0) 
In Harris Corner detector a score is determined by using eigenvalues of a 2*2 matrix. If both the eigenvalues are small then that means it was a flat region. It's explained very well in this OpenCV tutorial. Then you can refine the identified flat region using color information. It should reasonably handle the perspective transformations.

Comment: Could you please give a bit more info about your points 1 and 3? What is variance in this case and how is it computed for a region? In addition, regarding point 2, are u suggesting ignoring S and V values? It sounds feasible. I would really appreciate if you could explain it further. Thanks a lot

Comment: Here variance is same as statistical variance of data points. Compute variance on V channel to detect flat regions. Then, use H channel for refining the detected regions according to the preferred color. You can ignore S channel, as it tells you pureness of  the hue.

Comment: How would V channel helo to find regions?

Comment: May be I could use HSI in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can use HSI color space. I = (R+G+B)/3. So it contains the luma of an image. you can use it to detect flat regions in the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you reconsider your second point, finding circled objects, you should actually look for ellipses because of the the angle to the object. To detect ellipses in a picture I copy pasted a code from the book Practical OpenCV by Samarth Brahmbhatt (you should find it on Google). The theory of the used algorithm is this article: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=765658